# Usar inner join com BindingSource

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta em um banco access utilizando `inner join` juntamente com `BindingSource`, esse binding vai enviar os dados para um `Datagridview`.

Porém, quando os dados são carregados no grid, os resultados exibidos são de um `select` comum e não do `inner join` estou procurando a solução a algum tempo e não consegui achar.

Segue trecho do código para agregar os dados ao datagrid

```
private void VinculaDadosDataGridView()
    {
        try
        {
            conn = new OleDbConnection(strConexaoSQL);
            conn.Close();
            string query = @"SELECT Inventario.Código, Polos.Polo, Inventario.Tipo, Inventario.Equipamento, Inventario.Marca,
                             Inventario.Modelo, Inventario.NS, Inventario.Patrimonio, Inventario.[Constar no CC], Inventario.Usuario
                             FROM (Inventario
                             INNER JOIN Polos ON Inventario.Alocado_em = Polos.Código);";
            conn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds, "Inventario");
            bs.DataSource = ds;
            bs.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName;
            dgvDados.DataSource = bs;
            formataGridView();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            //dr.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Não sei se é importante, mas segue trecho do formataGridView

```
private void formataGridView()
    {
        var grd = dgvDados;
        //grd.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        //grd.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        grd.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders;
        grd.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Single;
        grd.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        //altera a cor das linhas alternadas no grid
        grd.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        grd.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
        /*//altera o nome das colunas
        grd.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Código";
        grd.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Alocado em";
        grd.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Tipo";
        grd.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Equipamento";
        grd.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Marca";
        grd.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Modelo";
        grd.Columns[6].HeaderText = "NS";
        grd.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Patrimônio";
        grd.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Constar no CC";
        grd.Columns[9].HeaderText = "Outros";
        //largura colunas
        grd.Columns[0].Width = 50;
        grd.Columns[1].Width = 150;
        grd.Columns[2].Width = 150;
        grd.Columns[3].Width = 150;
        grd.Columns[4].Width = 150;
        grd.Columns[5].Width = 150;
        grd.Columns[6].Width = 150;
        grd.Columns[7].Width = 150;
        grd.Columns[8].Width = 150;
        grd.Columns[9].Width = 150;*/
        //seleciona a linha inteira
        grd.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        //não permite seleção de multiplas linhas
        grd.MultiSelect = false;
        // exibe nulos formatados
        //grd.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = " - ";
        //permite que o texto maior que célula não seja truncado
        grd.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
    }
```

Resultado
[image: resultado]

Reparem que a coluna `alocado_em` continua em `ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### O OleDbCommand recebe uma query normal de banco.

### Vê se esse funciona:

string query = @"SELECT
inv.Código
, Polos.Polo
, inv.Tipo
, inv.Equipamento
, inv.Marca
, inv.Modelo
, inv.NS
, inv.Patrimonio
, inv.[Constar no CC]
, inv.Usuario
FROM inventario inv
INNER JOIN polos
ON inv.alocado_em = polos.código;"

### Quanto ao OleDbDataAdapter deixe apenas o DataSet com um argumento.

da.Fill(ds)

Comment: Não deu certo e quando eu altero o da.Fill(ds, "Invenario") para da.Fill(ds) o código passa a ignorar a formatação onde eu escondo o campo código (sim, o datagrid precisa ter este campo e esconde-lo).

Comment: Os dados estão retornando errado ainda?
bs.DataMember = "Inventario";

Comment: Ainda retornam errado, percebi que mesmo retirando algum campo da query, o código ignora e trás o campo mesmo assim, quanto ao DataMember, ele não aceitou da maneira que você indicou.

Comment: Tenta chamando o método formataGridView() depois do bloco finally{}

Comment: Também não foi, mesmo sem o formataGridView ele não mostra corretamente, ele da o select normal sem JOIN e pega todos mesmo excluindo.

Comment: Fiz um teste e preenchi o DataGridView diretamente com o DataSet, aparentemente quem está ignorando a consulta é o BindingSource, não sei se isso vai ajudar, estou utilizando o BindingSource para usar a função "Filter" em consultas futuras.